# If two invertible matrices agree on a vector, does this imply their determinant agrees as well?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, determinant

As stated, if we let $A, B \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be invertible and there is some $v\in R^n$ such that 
$$Av = Bv$$
does it follow that $\det(A) = \det(B)$?

Additionally, does this hold if we let $A, B \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: No, but you **do** know that $\det (A-B) = 0$ (assuming $v \neq 0$).

Comment: How many examples did you try before you asked this question?

Comment: 0 - I was busy when I asked this but it popped into my head. I suspected it was easy, but my mind was otherwise engaged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. As a counterexample consider
$$A= \left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{matrix} \right)
$$

$$
B=\left( \begin{matrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{matrix} \right)
$$
and
$$v=\left( \begin{matrix}
0  \\
1 
\end{matrix} \right)
$$

Comment: @TedShifrin both of those matrices are invertible.

Comment: Sorry, I swear I saw 0's at the bottom :P My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider eigenvectors and eigenvalues and diagonalizable invertible matrices. If $A$ and $B$ have one eigenvector $v$ in common with the same eigenvalue, so that $Av = Bv$, does that mean that all the other eigenvalues are equal, or for that matter, the products of eigenvalues are equal? (which is the determinant)

Answer (score 0):

No. Counter eg:$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \left[ \begin{array}{c} 2 \\ 1 \end{array} \right] = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}  \left[ \begin{array}{c} 2 \\ 1 \end{array} \right]$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the matrices
$$A= \begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 0  \\
    0       & 2  
\end{bmatrix},B= \begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 0  \\
    0       & 1  
\end{bmatrix}$$

Can you find a vector $v$ such that $Av=Bv$?  Do $A$ and $B$ have the same determinant?